# Using nested XML data to display in HTML Table

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming XML to HTML table using XSLT but stuck on one point where XML has multiple data as below

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Table>
        <Rating>Existing Internal Ratings</Rating>
        <Financial_Year>2011-12</Financial_Year>
        <Internal_Rating>SB-7</Internal_Rating>
        <Validation_Date>28.02.2017</Validation_Date>
        <Long_Term_Rating/>
        <Short_Term_Rating/>
        <Expiry_Date/>
        <Rating_Amount/>
    </Table>

    <Table>
        <Rating>Previous Internal Ratings</Rating>
        <Financial_Year>2010-11</Financial_Year>
        <Internal_Rating>SB-9</Internal_Rating>
        <Validation_Date>25.02.2016</Validation_Date>
        <Long_Term_Rating/>
        <Short_Term_Rating/>
        <Expiry_Date/>
        <Rating_Amount/>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Rating>Dynamic Rating</Rating>
        <Financial_Year/>
        <Internal_Rating>28.02.2017</Internal_Rating>
        <Validation_Date/>
        <Long_Term_Rating/>
        <Short_Term_Rating/>
        <Expiry_Date/>
        <Rating_Amount/>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Rating>Existing External Ratings</Rating>
        <Financial_Year/>
        <Internal_Rating/>
        <Validation_Date/>
        <Long_Term_Rating>BBB+</Long_Term_Rating>
        <Short_Term_Rating>B1</Short_Term_Rating>
        <Expiry_Date>31.03.2017</Expiry_Date>
        <Rating_Amount>125</Rating_Amount>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <Rating>Previous External Ratings</Rating>
        <Financial_Year/>
        <Internal_Rating/>
        <Validation_Date/>
        <Long_Term_Rating>A+</Long_Term_Rating>
        <Short_Term_Rating>A2</Short_Term_Rating>
        <Expiry_Date>28.02.2016</Expiry_Date>
        <Rating_Amount>212</Rating_Amount>
    </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

To display the data in table I want to fetch data from XML on the basis of the **Rating** tag. This is the only Identifier present in that XML data.

**XSLT I am using for this is as below**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>                
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <!--<meta charset="utf-8" />-->
                <!--<title></title>-->
                <!--<style type="text/css">-->
                <style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0px auto;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:3px 11px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:3px 11px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-123c{font-weight:bold;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-xnj0{font-weight:bold;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;background-color:#3166ff;text-align:center}
.tg .tg-g145{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-smzr{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-gh1y{font-weight:bold;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-20ea{font-weight:bold;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;background-color:#3531ff;text-align:center}
.tg .tg-62yd{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;background-color:#ffffff}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <table class="tg">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="tg-20ea" colspan="3">Internal Ratings</th>
                        <th class="tg-20ea">Dynamic Rating</th>
                        <th class="tg-62yd" rowspan="6"/>
                        <th class="tg-xnj0" colspan="3">External Ratings</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tg-smzr"/>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Existing</td>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Previous</td>
                        <td class="tg-smzr" rowspan="2"/>
                        <td class="tg-123c">Agency</td>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Existing (CARE)</td>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Previous (CRISIL)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Financial Year</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">2011-12</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">2010-11</td>
                        <td class="tg-123c">Long Term Rating</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">BBB+</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">A+</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y" rowspan="2">Internal Rating</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145" rowspan="2">SB-7</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145" rowspan="2">SB-9</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145" rowspan="2">SB-7</td>
                        <td class="tg-123c">Short Term Rating</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">B1</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">A2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tg-123c">Expiry Date</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">31.03.2017</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">28.02.2016</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Validation Date</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">28.02.2017</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">25.02.2016</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">31.03.2016</td>
                        <td class="tg-123c">Rating Amount</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">125</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145">212</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </body>
        </html>         
    </xsl:template>                     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to dynamically change the data which are not highlighted in bold in the sample output image.

**Expected Output :**
[image]

Currently I am passing hard coded values in the XSLT which are present in Input XML. 
**Is their any way to fetch other tags data from nested XML on the basis of the data present in specific tag? Like Rating tag present in mentioned XML data.**

I want  to something like below which we can do in SQL.

```
SELECT Financial_Year FROM Table WHERE Rating = 'First'
SELECT Financial_Year FROM Table WHERE Rating = 'Second'
```

I tried to fetch the values in one of the `td` as below but it is returning blank in the output.

```
<tr>
    <td class="tg-gh1y">Validation Date</td>
    <td class="tg-g145">28.02.2017</td>
    <td class="tg-g145">25.02.2016</td>
    <td class="tg-g145">31.03.2016</td>
    <td class="tg-123c">Rating Amount</td>
    <td class="tg-g145">125</td>
    <td class="tg-g145">
        <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'First']/Internal_Rating"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Using XSLT to get expected output. If there are any suggestions then let me know.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>                
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <!--<meta charset="utf-8" />-->
                <!--<title></title>-->
                <!--<style type="text/css">-->
                <style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0px auto;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:3px 11px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:3px 11px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-123c{font-weight:bold;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-xnj0{font-weight:bold;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;background-color:#3166ff;text-align:center}
.tg .tg-g145{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-smzr{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-gh1y{font-weight:bold;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-20ea{font-weight:bold;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;background-color:#3531ff;text-align:center}
.tg .tg-62yd{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;;background-color:#ffffff}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <table class="tg">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="tg-20ea" colspan="3">Internal Ratings</th>
                        <th class="tg-20ea">Dynamic Rating</th>
                        <th class="tg-62yd" rowspan="6"/>
                        <th class="tg-xnj0" colspan="3">External Ratings</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tg-smzr"/>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Existing</td>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Previous</td>
                        <td class="tg-smzr" rowspan="2"/>
                        <td class="tg-123c">Agency</td>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Existing (CARE)</td>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Previous (CRISIL)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Financial Year</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Existing Internal Ratings']/Financial_Year"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Previous Internal Ratings']/Financial_Year"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-123c">Long Term Rating</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Existing External Ratings']/Long_Term_Rating"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Previous External Ratings']/Long_Term_Rating"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y" rowspan="2">Internal Rating</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145" rowspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Existing Internal Ratings']/Internal_Rating"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-g145" rowspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Previous Internal Ratings']/Internal_Rating"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-g145" rowspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Dynamic Rating']/Internal_Rating"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-123c">Short Term Rating</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Existing External Ratings']/Short_Term_Rating"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Previous External Ratings']/Short_Term_Rating"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tg-123c">Expiry Date</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Existing External Ratings']/Expiry_Date"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Previous External Ratings']/Expiry_Date"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tg-gh1y">Validation Date</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Existing Internal Ratings']/Validation_Date"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Previous Internal Ratings']/Validation_Date"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Dynamic Rating']/Validation_Date"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-123c">Rating Amount</td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Existing External Ratings']/Rating_Amount"/></td>
                        <td class="tg-g145"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'Previous External Ratings']/Rating_Amount"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </body>
        </html>         
    </xsl:template>                     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XPath expression corresponds to the SQL statement you have given as an example:

```
//Table[Rating = 'First']/Financial_Year
```

Applying this to your input gives:

```
> xmllint --xpath "//Table[Rating = 'First']/Financial_Year" test.xml 
<Financial_Year>2011-12</Financial_Year>
```

Comment: Does this work in XSLT using below command. <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="//Table[Rating = 'First']/Financial_Year"/>
            </td>

Comment: In principle yes, but that mostly depends on how you want your resulting HTML to look like. Please update the question with an example of how exactly the result should look. And please also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: The data I want to display have large table. The question I asked using small part of the same. As of now,  I have tried to select specific data using `<td><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table[Rating = 'First']/Internal_Rating"/></td>`.

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure if your problem is solved. Does it work as it should?

Comment: No. It is not fetching expected data. In Node `Internal_Rating` presents `SB-7` value. I am expecting the same in output.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of your answer. Please show the complete HTML document you're expecting from the sample you provided.

Comment: I have updated my question and the thing which I tried.

Comment: It is working now. I forget to change the condition. Thank you very much. Apologized for my mistake.